# Usage of function instead of module in vba for DML operations

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with Name as `MyTable` which has field `Names(TEXT)` which has values, `'MFG@#'`, `'jkl%980'`, I have written a function to remove special character like this

```
Function fn_RemoveSpecialChars(strText As String) As Boolean

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    Dim output As String
    Dim c
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
            c = Mid(strText, i, 1)
            If (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "0" And c <= "9") Or (c >= "A" And c <= "Z") Then
                output = output & c
            Else
                output = output & ""
            End If
        Next

        fn_RemoveSpecialChars = LTrim(RTrim(output))
    End Function`
```

I am using command click to utilize function to update in `MyTable` like this

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

db.Execute "Update MyTable set Names=fn_RemoveSpecialChars(Names)"

End Sub
```

If i use the same function as module then it works fine for me, But if i use like a function shown above then it won't work, May be because `UPDATE` is DML Operation. Because of some user requirement i can't use Modules or procedures, So Is there any alternate way to achieve above ?, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Input : MFG@#$123
Output: MFG123

Comment: What exactly is *won't work* ?

Comment: i mean, updation is not happening, it shows unrecognized udf, same if i use in module, db.execute "update MyTable set Names=fn_RemoveSpecialChars(Names)" will work

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *use the function as module*? I don't understand this - we have a language problem here.

Comment: Your `db.Execute` needs to be altered: `db.Execute "UPDATE MyTable set Names= '" & fn_RemoveSpecialChars(Names) & "' WHERE ...`. (altered quotations and added where-clause). I'm not sure if this will fix your problem though. And a small thing: if there is no need for an `else`-statement, then leave it out.

Comment: Module is a type where you can write functions

Comment: Calris, that way it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the wrong data type - it must be string, not boolean.

```
Function fn_RemoveSpecialChars(strText As String) As String
```

Comment: and my code works absolutely if i use it as module, but because of user requirement i am not using module and need alternate solution for the above